# Módulo en C++ para proyecto ruleta

Tags: c++

Trato de desarrollar un módulo para un proyecto de universidad de la Ruleta, y he de desarrollar el siguiente módulo, pero hay varios aspectos que no me quedan claros, porque me da fallo en una declaración, pero no sé cómo solucionarla. Mi módulo sigue las premisas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y mi código es el siguiente:

```
// Módulo Jugador

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

char Apuesta = "numero";

void solicitarJugador(struct Jugador); 

void actualizarSaldo(Jugador &jugador, int numeroRuleta, Apuesta & apuesta);
 
struct Jugador{
    
    char jugador[20];
    
    long int saldo;
    
};

void solicitarJugador(struct Jugador){
    
    char jugador;
    cout<< "\nIntroduce el nombre del jugador\n:";
    cin>> jugador;
    
    long int saldo;
    cout<< "\nIntroduce el saldo del jugador or favor:";
    cin >> saldo;
    
    struct Jugador;
    
}

void actualizarSaldo(Jugador &jugador, int numeroRuleta, Apuesta & apuesta){
    
    if (Apuesta == 'par' && int numeroRuleta%2==0 && int numeroRuleta != 0){
        saldo_jugador = saldo_jugador + Apuesta;
    }
    else{
        if (Apuesta == 'par' && int numeroRuleta%2==0 && int numeroRuleta == 0){
            saldo_jugador = saldo_jugador - Apuesta;
        }
        if(Apuesta == 'impar' && int numeroRuleta%2 != 0){
            saldo_jugador = saldo_jugador + Apuesta;
        }
        if(Apuesta == 'número' && int numeroRuleta == int Apuesta){
            saldo_jugador = saldo_jugador + 35*Apuesta;
        }
    }
    else{
        saldo_jugador = saldo_jugador - Apuesta;
    }
    
    cout<< "\nEl nuevo saldo del jugador"
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué error te da concretamente? Sé más preciso en tus explicaciones y así podremos ayudarte.

Comment: Pon además el enunciado _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes.

Comment: Como primera observación, si te están pidiendo que definas una función con este protitipo: `void solicitarJugador(Jugador& jugador);`pues tendrás que respetarlo en tu código

Comment: Yo le pondría `nombre` al arreglo en lugar de `jugador`.

Comment: Necesitaria saber como probar que este modulo funciona de forma correcta, dado que el argumento de Apuesta me da como no declarado

Comment: `Apuesta` no es un tipo de dato. No puedes usarlo de esa manera como parámetro. Además es de tipo char pero le asignas una cadena. En todo caso usa `char* Apuesta = "numero"` o si necesitas modificarlo, `char Apuesta[20] = "numero"`.

Answer (score 0):

Tu código tiene muchos fallos, la verdad. Por empezar, están pidiendo una función con esta firma:

```
void solicitarJugador(Jugador& jugador);
```

Es decir, has de crear el tipo Jugador (que ya lo has hecho), luego crear una instancia de este tipo, y luego darle nombre y saldo por medio de la función.

Algo como:

```
int main()
{
    //defino un jugador
    Jugador j1;
    solicitarJugador(j1);
    .....
    return 0;
}
```

Y luego la función es trivial:

```
void solicitarJugador(Jugador& jugador)

{
    cout<< "\nIntroduce el nombre del jugador\n:";
    cin>> jugador.nombre;
    cout<< "\nIntroduce el saldo del jugador or favor:";
    cin >> jugador.saldo;
}
```

Luego está lo de la Apuesta. No nos das datos sobre cómo es, pero se entiende que debe de ser otro tipo estructurado. Yo la definiría así:

```
enum eTipoApuesta {par,impar,numero};

struct Apuesta
{
    eTipoApuesta tipo;
    int numero;
    long int cantidad;
};
```

Ya que tenemos que saber tres cosas.

1.- La cantidad a apostar

2.- El tipo de apuesta

3.- Si el tipo de apuesta es a número, saber a qué numero se va a apostar.

Y una vez definido el tipo Apuesta, podemos operar con él en la función:

```
void actualizarSaldo(Jugador &jugador, int numeroRuleta, Apuesta & apuesta)
{
    if (apuesta.tipo == par && numeroRuleta%2 == 0 && numeroRuleta != 0)
    {
        jugador.saldo = jugador.saldo + apuesta.cantidad;
    }
    else if(apuesta.tipo == impar && numeroRuleta%2 != 0)
    {
        jugador.saldo = jugador.saldo + apuesta.cantidad;
    }
    else if(apuesta.tipo == numero && numeroRuleta == apuesta.numero)
    {
        jugador.saldo = jugador.saldo + apuesta.cantidad*35;
    }
    else
    {
        jugador.saldo = jugador.saldo - apuesta.cantidad;
    }
}
```

Puedes ver un ejemplo completo en [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/TS1e69wx)

Comment: muchas gracias por las aportaciones realizadas, muy amables.